# How can i create a new folder and copy specific types of files in it , in my CI/CD pipeline

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am running a CI/CD pipeline on gitlab and in deployement I want to create a new folder which will copy whole directory structure but only .pyc files in it

**This is my deploy job code**

```
deploy-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  environment: production
  script:
    - mkdir trial
    - find . -name '*.pyc' -exec cp --parents \{\} ~/trial \;
    - echo "files successfully delivered."
```

Is it possible to create a new directory in my gitlab repository with the given requirements ?